# Formula en excel para susituir valores

Tags: excel

solicito la ayuda de la comunidad para resolver algo en excel, en realidad no soy usuario asiduo de excel lo uso a nivel basico pero ahora se me presenta esta situacion que tengo que formlar por que son muchos registros.

Alguien podria orientarme en como hacer lo siguiente:
Necesito buscar en la columna E todos los numeros que coincidan con la columna C y cambiarlos por su respectivo de la columna D.

Por ejemplo en la columna E el numero 10 en la posicion 1956 esta tambien en la columna C en la posicion 1958 entonces tendria que sustituirlo por el valor 45 de la columna D tambien en la posicion 1958

Ojala haya sido entendible lo que escribi por que en realidad necesito resolver esto.
De antemano gracias a todos.
Gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio, y lee [¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

Miguel lo que tienes que usar la fórmula BUSCARV. Si no lo encuentra asumo que usas el valor de E.
En una nueva columna, fila 2: `=SI.ERROR(BUSCARV(E2, C:D, 2, FALSO), E2)`
Estiras esta fórmula a lo largo de la tabla y pegas como valor el resultado en "E"

Comment: Gracias hermano funciona super....